# Plot from a file

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph in python with matplotlib. The file i am trying to give as input is txt file with no delimiter. It has many columns and I am interested in `col[2]` and `col[4]`. The data could be `str or int or float`.

Input file

```
3401  1772  1  0.0002  3498.0
3840  3730  5  0.001  4658.0
3439  651  13  0.0026  22208.0
5069  3354  2  0.0004  3510.0
5252  4001  5  0.001  3468.0
5417  2970  5  0.001  4224.0
4653  3928  5  0.001  10132.0
1681  1028  2  0.0004  9399.0
2908  2615  4  0.0008  19306.0
```

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import*
import math
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator

plt.plotfile('edge_per_one_1.txt', delimiter=' ', cols=(2,4), names=('col2','col4'), marker='o')

plt.show()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_data.py", line 7, in <module>
    plt.plotfile('edge_per_one_1.txt', delimiter=' ', cols=(2,4), names=('col2','col4'), marker='o')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1894, in plotfile
    xname, x = getname_val(cols[0])
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1889, in getname_val
    name = r.dtype.names[int(identifier)]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: All of them seem to be correct. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed column names in `names` argument. Also your input file seems to have DOUBLE SPACES as delimiters. Delimiters should be SINGLE CHAR items(space or comma).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plotfile('edge_per_one_1.txt', delimiter=' ', cols=(2,4), 
              names=('col1','col2','col3','col4','col5'), marker='o')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Clue is in the stacktrace:

```
File "pyplot.py", line 2318, in getname_val
name = r.dtype.names[int(identifier)]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Looks like the getname_val passed is too short. Looking in the code itself:

```
        elif is_numlike(identifier):
        name = r.dtype.names[int(identifier)]
```

It looks like it is trying to access the names by index you provided. This means that you must provide all of the column names to plotfile,

```
plt.plotfile('edge_per_one_1.txt', delimiter=' ', cols=(2,4), names=('col1','col2','col3','col4','col5'), marker='o')
```

In short: the names argument requires you to give the names of all columns

Answer (score 0):

You could also provide axes label using pyplot :

```
plt.plotfile('edge_per_one_1.txt', delimiter=' ', cols=(2,4), marker='o')
plt.xlabel("col2")
plt.ylabel("col4")
```